# Relationship between noncommutative torus for different values of theta

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory

Let $u,v\in B(L_2(\mathbb T))$ defined as $u(f)(z)=zf(z)$ and $v(f)(z)=f(ze^{-2\pi i\theta})$ for $z\in\mathbb T$ where $\theta\in\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb{Q}$. Denote the $C^*$ algebra generated by $u$ and $v$ to be $\mathbb T_\theta^d$ which is called a noncommutative torus. Let $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ be two irrational numbers with $|\theta_1-\theta_2|<\epsilon$. Is it true that there exists a $C^*$ homomorphism  $\Phi:\mathbb{T}_{\theta_1}^d\to\mathbb{T}_{\theta_2}^d$  such that $\|\Phi\|<\epsilon$?

Comment: Every non-zero $*$-homomorphism between $C^\ast$-algebras has norm 1.

Comment: @JamieGabe It is even more basic than that... see my answer

Answer (score 4):

Jamie Gabe has already pointed out why the answer is negative, but I wanted to point out that in fact the negative answer has nothing to do with Cstar algebras, quantum tori, or anything beyond the definition of a Banach algebra. The result follows easily from the following observations.

Observation 1. If $A$ is a Banach algebra and $p$ is a non-zero idempotent in $A$, then $\lVert p\rVert \geq 1$. (Hint: use the fact that the norm is submultiplicative.)

Observation 2. If $A$ and $B$ are unital rings, and $\phi:A\to B$ is a ring homomorphism such that $\phi(1_A)=0$, then $\phi\equiv 0$.